# Why doesn't $R^3$ span $R^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We're now covering the topic of vector spaces in linear algebra, and my GSI pointed out the fact that $R^3$ does not span $R^2$. Or better, vectors in $R^3$ do not span $R^2$. Why is this?

From my geometric understanding, the span of $R^2$ is simply a plane in $R^3$. The material is becoming increasingly abstract, so there's definitely a gap of understanding here. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to consider the inclusion $\mathbb R^2\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ as being truthful. It isn't. "If it was true", you'd be right.

Comment: what's a GSI?...

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249927/why-do-we-say-that-two-vectors-in-r3-cannot-span-r2

Comment: @WillJagy Graduate Student Instructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is **not** a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.  Why?  Let's think about it.

If you have a set $X$, then another set $A$ is a subset of $X$ if every element in $A$ is in $X$.

Now, elements of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ look like $(a,b,c)$ for real numbers $a,b,c$.  If you have an element of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then the element is a vector with $3$ components.  So if you have a set that is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then every element of that subset must have $3$ components.

But elements of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ look like $(a,b)$ for real numbers $a,b$.  So if you have an element of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then it is a vector with $2$ components.  This can't be in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ because every element of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ has $3$ components.

So, this means if you have any set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, they *can't* span $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ because they aren't even in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ -- they each have three components.  Any set of vectors that would span $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (or any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$) must be a set of vectors with only two components.

Similarly, you can't ever span $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (or any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$) with vectors that come from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  This is again because vectors that live in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ have $2$ components.

Finally, I want to mention that a $2$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is **isomorphic** to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but the vectors in the $2$-dimensional plane have three components each, and the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ have two components each.  This means that even the $XY$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is **not equal** to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but they are not equal.  The vectors in the $XY$-plane subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ have $3$ components, while the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ have only two components.

I know I repeated the same idea over and over in my answer, but hopefully you now have a better understanding of why no set of vectors from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ can span $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

May be I have misunderstood your question but

i) If I have to prove $$\Bbb R^2\neq Sp\{\Bbb R^3\}$$

$\Bbb R^2 = Sp\{(a,b),(c,d)\}$ extend it to $Sp\{(a,b,0),(c,d,0),(e,f,g)\}= \Bbb R^3$[Actually it is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$]. But $(e,f,g)\notin \Bbb R^2$. So $\Bbb R^2 \neq Sp\{\Bbb R^3\}$

ii) If I have to prove $$\Bbb R^3\neq Sp\{\Bbb R^2\}$$

Then $\Bbb R^2 = Sp\{(a,b),(c,d)\}$. Now if it can be shown that $Sp\{(a,b),(c,d)\} \cong Sp\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. But $(0,0,z) \in \Bbb R^3$ &  $(0,0,z) \notin Sp\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. So, $\Bbb R^3 \neq Sp\{\Bbb R^2\}$

Comment: You are mistaken, $\mathbb{R}^2=Sp\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, which is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  This is a common misunderstanding.

Comment: See  math.stackexchange.com/questions/249927/… here also it was written what I have said. Again I never said both are equal, I said that they are isomorphic. Actually $\Bbb R^2$ is included in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: May be I can't get what you actually want to say   vadim123.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948692/is-it-possible-to-express-a-vector-in-mathbbr2-with-a-vector-with-n-comp

Comment: If you look at the answer to the question you just posted, you will see that you are mistaken.

Comment: What do I have to prove $\Bbb R^2$ does not span $\Bbb R^3$ or $\Bbb R^3$ does not span $\Bbb R^2$??

Comment: @ vadim123 & @rosstex Now please check. I have considered all possible cases.